# How to use forloop iteration variable inside onclicklistener method of a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, for-loop

this is my code..

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
   {
          buttons[i] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // in this method I want to set the button text to the iteration variable 'i'
        }
    });
   }
```

my need is to get the iteration variable inside the onclick method. I tried by assigning the i value to another int variable(with and without using final) before the onclick method. But all this shows some errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make the i variable global by declaring it at the top of your class outside methods. `private int i;`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable

Then you don't need to say `int` inside the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
   {
         buttons[i] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // in this method I want to set the button text to the iteration variable 'i'
        }
    });
   }
```

You could also use the final modifier as mentioned in the comments, you would have to post how you tried to use it if you wanted us to debug your error.

Comment: or use a final modifier (just to be complete)

Comment: Yes that too but he said he tried that and it didn't work, some error on his part. I will add in what you say.

Comment: @paul when i do that i get this error. "cannot refer to a non final variable "i" inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: @Paul thanks. That worked. I made the iteration variable global as you suggested. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: No problem glad to help, as for the error you were getting that means you didn't have i as final and were referring to it.

Comment: If you make I global, wont all the buttons set the text to 12?

Comment: Depending on what he wants to do there are different ways of handling this, from what I can see any button he presses inside that loop will be the iteration value, which seems to be what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could move away from having the `i` variable as a global/final variable, and use the `setTag()` method of `Button` to pass the value through.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          buttons[i] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
          buttons[i].setTag(new Integer(i));
          buttons[i].setOnClickListener(listener);
   }
```

And separate out the `OnClickListener`:

```
    OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               Integer iHolder = v.getTag();
               int i = iHolder.intValue();
               // set button text
        }
    };
```

This way the `Button` itself holds the reference to the value of `i` instead of it floating around globally or being declared `final`.